# Rails render template with status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the simplest/shortest way to respond in an API controller.  Currently the following works:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render 'client', status: :ok }
end
```

however this controller will only ever respond to json (respond_to :json) so the whole respond_to do |format| thing seems like unnecessary code.

Ideally I would just like to do something simple like:

```
render 'client', status: :ok
```

**Update:**
I neglected to mention that: 'client' is a jbuilder template that does not match my action name.

Comment: A better way would be to use respond_with: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with

Comment: How would one use respond_with in the example above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use render directly

```
render json: 'client', status: :ok
```

Comment: I should've been clearer: client is a jbuilder template that I want to render.  the solution you propose will return a json string 'client'

Answer (score 3):

According to @hassasin, you can indicate your controller to `render json:` format on each action of your controller.

Other option is to take advantage of your `config.routes.rb` to set the entire response format of your controller, e.g. `contacts_controller`:

```
resources :contacts, defaults: {format: :json}
```

If you want to indicate the `status`, add this to your actions:

```
def index
  render status: :ok # 200, 400, 500, what ever you want
end
```

I tested the code above with Rails 3.2.16

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `json` views (assume you are using `jbuilder`), you dont need that render statement if your action name matches the view name.

Comment: Thanks steve, unfortunately my view name cannot match my action.

Comment: then just do a render. thats all. no need to specify format.